# Programmatically scroll a Picker View up or down

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

As you can see here, the toolbar above the Picker View has both next and back button, and I want to scroll the Picker view programmatically up and down when the user clicks on those buttons. I am not able to get how to do the same. Please help me in understanding how to implement the same.

[image]

Comment: use func selectRow(_ row: Int, inComponent component: Int, animated: Bool) of UIPickerView

Comment: Every time you see a picker view being scrolled it is because a new item is being selected. You can have a private variable that points to your last `realSelected` item (which I guess is when someone presses "Done"?), but in order to scroll using `<` and `>`, you need `selectRow`

Comment: @regina_fallangi, i got it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your`<` and `>` buttons need to have actions associated, let's do an example for "selectNext". I am going to assume you only have one component:

```
var myElements: [SomeType] = // whichever elements you are displaying
var pickerView: UIPickerView // maybe an outlet or an initialised programmatically variable

@objc func selectNext() {
    let currentSelectedRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    guard currentSelectedRow < myElements.count else {
        return
    }
    if currentSelectedRow + 1 < myElements.count {
        pickerView.selectRow(currentSelectedRow + 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    } else { // next element is 0th of list
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }        
}
```

The `selectPrevious` function would follow the same suit. You can also add more checks to make sure that the element you are going to select is not out of bounds, or that `myElements` contains elements.

Comment: please check your answer, there are so many spelling mistakes. Please correct them

Comment: @ArshadShaik, would you mind to give me an example of a spelling mistake you are seeing?

Comment: please check the pickerView.selecteRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: 0) 
it should be picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)            
"animated can be false or true"

Comment: @ArshadShaik, thanks! In StackOverflow it is also possible to do the edits yourself, it does not need to be the author. Corrected `curentSelectedRow` -> `currentSelectedRow` as well anyway

Comment: when i tried to edit yesterday, it says edit queue full. So i asked you to edit.